# Getting Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' error while sending confirmation email to email address

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to send confirmation mail after signing up with email password with firebase and next.js . I am new to both next.js & firebase so I'm having some difficulties.

The problem is, I am getting a confirmation mail in my email but before I confirm and redirect to the page , it's automatically redirecting to the homepage. So ultimately there is no point of mail confirmation.

I think somehow the `emailVerified` is always `true` which I need to stop.
I have tried with this block of code but not working.

```
const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        if (res.user) {
            firebaseAdmin.auth().updateUser(res.user.uid, { emailVerified: false });
            sendEmailVerification(res.user);
            router.push('/');
        }
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js:22:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

When I remove `firebaseAdmin.auth().updateUser(res.user.uid, { emailVerified: false });` this line, then the error is solved but then I am not getting any confirmation mail.

Can anyone please help with this?